# ProLiant DL320e Gen8 v2 cannot see disk on SAS ports, SATA port 5 (for dvd-drive) works fine

Tags: hp-proliant, software-raid

First post on this forum, thanks for reading.

Trying to get my server up and running with a RAID0 array on the built in software RAID controller HP Dynamic Smart Array B120i v3.54.

The system does see some consumer sata drives with 500gb.
But it cannont detect nor see original HP 2TB SAS drives (part #652757) which are compatible with this particular unit.

I've tried with 4 different disks, all 652757 ones. 2 of them gives orange steady light on the caddy. 2 others does not light up in the caddy.
The caddy does try to initialise. I've also tried 2 brand new Seagate 2TB sas disks, they are not seen by the system either.

In the raid controller software/settings there is no trace of the disks either so I cannot create logical disk/arryas. None of them shows.

I've tried on a mint DL320e Gen8 v2 also, with exact same results. This unit has not been updated since 2014 regarding firmwares.

Only a consumer SSD sata that I've tried to connect to the PORT5 SATA on the motherboard works (port normally for super slim DVD-drive). I shows in boot-process, in the raid-settings utily and I can install a OS on it etc.

All firmware are updated, I've tried deleting NAND flash also. No luck.

Does any body now what to do - am I missing something obvius?

Thanks :)

Product ID: 717170-421
System ROM: P80 04/04/2019
System ROM Date: 04/04/2019
Backup System ROM: P80 03/28/2014

iLO Firmware Version: 2.78 Apr 28 2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad news... B120i does NOT support SAS drives, SATA only. You can add additional "P" smart array controller for example P222, P421 and connect sas cables from backplane to this controller.

https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c03326739

Comment: Thanks alot. I guess I did miss out on something obvius.

I do not understand why the reseller of the drives and the compatible drives list from HP states that theese SAS disks are compatible with the unit, as it ships on default with th B120i controller :(